# What do "-" user in django admin mean? Can't delete or open

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I'm trying to learn Django and following a tutorial, I have a "-" user in my Customer Model, I'm not sure where it came from. If I attempt to delete or open it, the error below appears. I tried to verify if my Customer Model is working by deleting other named users and It's working fine. What does the "-" entry means? Thank you for the help.

[Customer Model Image in Django admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFlMu.png)

TypeError at /admin/accounts/customer/3/change/
**str** returned non-string (type NoneType)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/accounts/customer/3/change/
Django Version: 4.1.3
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:
**str** returned non-string (type NoneType)
Exception Location: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py, line 1859, in _changeform_view
Raised during:  django.contrib.admin.options.change_view
Python Executable:  C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe
Python Version: 3.11.0
Python Path:
['C:\Users\user\Desktop\crm',
'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python311.zip',
'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib',
'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\DLLs',
'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311',
'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages']
Server time:    Sun, 01 Jan 2023 15:43:55 +0000

I tried to verify if my Customer Model is working by deleting other named users and It's working fine.

[models.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wh50.png)

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(default="profile1.png", null=True, blank=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Product(models.Model):
    CATEGORY = (
        ("Indoor", "Indoor"),
        ("Outdoor", "Outdoor"),
    )

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    price = models.FloatField(null=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=CATEGORY)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Order(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
        ("Pending", "Pending"),
        ("Out for delivery", "Out for delivery"),
        ("Delivered", "Delivered"),
    )

    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=STATUS)
    note = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product.name
```

Comment: Please add your models.py.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Customer` model has literally *no* required fields.  Is there a reason for that?  Perhaps, though it would seem strange to me.

The problem, however, that is causing the error is that you can have a `Customer` that has *no* name, and yet you have:

```py
def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

So whenever you try to access this particular `Customer` with no name the `__str__` function returns `None` when the user of that `__str__` function, in this case the admin is expecting a string as output.

**The fix**
First, you shouldn't be making *every* field of every model null.
Second, usually `null=True` will go with `blank=True`, which allows forms, like change forms in the admin panel to have that field blank.

These should fix the problem, but will not allow you to get rid of the no name `Customer`, I believe.  To do that you have to, at least, temporarily, change the `__str__` function:

```py
def __str__(self):
    return self.name if self.name else 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
```